# Can we build and run a docker file using one single command from the command line

Tags: docker, dockerfile

I need to build a docker file and also run it at the same time.
How can I do that in a single command from the command line .

I tried in power shell command window-
 `docker build -t dockerwithmultiops . && docker run -d --name=dockerwithmultiops -p 8000-8002:8000-8002 dockerwithmultiops:latest`

It gives me this error -

```
+ docker build -t dockerwithmultiops . && docker run -d --name=dockerwi ...
+                                      ~~
The token '&&' is not a valid statement separator in this version.
    + CategoryInfo          : ParserError: (:) [], ParentContainsErrorRecordException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvalidEndOfLine
```

Answer (score 0):

`docker build -q .` outputs image hash, which you can use as the arguments to `docker run`. And add `--rm`, if you want the container removed automatically when it exits

```
docker run --rm -it $(docker build -q .)
```

You can try this command.